# How is this line of code code executing if only being defined?

Tags: php

How does this code execute, specifically `$result`? I'm a bit confused, because I thought you are just assigning some code to the variable `$result` , but it isn't actually being called.

For example I thought you had to do something like run it in a function, or activate it somehow ex: `runCode($result);` or just `mysqli_query($connection,$query);` without the variable in front.

Basically I thought that putting code in a variable definition causes it to not run automatically, even if that variable is a function such as the below example of `mysqli_query();`

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginapp");

  if ($username && $password && $connection) {
    $query ="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: The query is contained in the `$query` variable.  When you call `mysqli_query`, you are executing the `$query` on the `$connection`.  `https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php`.  It says **Performs a query on the database**.

Comment: You should use statement param for sql query to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @Nic3500
I had read the php.net manual documentation beforehand, but still don't understand. 
I get how it works, I don't get why it's being run while being initialized as a variable.

Like if the ```$result =``` part was gone, I understand that would be a pure function call and be run immediately. I thought that appending a variable to the front of that would prevent it from being immediately run?

Comment: The result of executing `mysqli_query` will be stored in `$result =`.  So in the doc, it says that `Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.`  So the $return is either FALSE, TRUE or a mysqli_result object.

Comment: The only difference between  `$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);` and `mysql_query($connection,$query)` is that the former stores the result for mysqli_query while the latter runs the query without storing the result anywhere. In both cases the query is executed. Think of it this way. When you assign a value to a variable, what are you assigning? Where do you get the value from? If mysqli_query doesn't run, what exactly is being assigned?

Comment: @Kei Thank you, that is exactly what I was having trouble understanding, makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign something to a variable, it is executed before the assignment. It's the same as:

```
$result = 5 + 4;
```

`5 + 4`, which returns `9`, is executed and then assigned to `$result`.

Your `mysqli_query($connection, $query);`, which returns a [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, is executed and then assigned to `$result`.